# I want to make my box offset, I tried putting the property but nothing happens. I use Tailwind & React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

this is the code i use in my CallToAction.js, i put -top-28:

```
<div className="border text-white h-[226px] w-auto mb-[389px] bg-brand-quaternary border-brand-primary rounded-lg place-items-center grid grid-cols-4 -top-28">
```

i want to make it like this:
[!pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrMtC.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrMtC.png)

but i get this:
[image: pic 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `mt-[-50%]` instead of `-top-28`. `Top` work with position property like `relative` and `absolute`. You can also use `-top-28` but you have to add `relative` or `absolute` class.

Comment: Thank you! Using -top-28 and adding relative to the class works well!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need `-top-28`?
Try it without the dash `top-28`

```
<div className="border text-white h-[226px] w-auto mb-[389px] bg-brand-quaternary border-brand-primary rounded-lg place-items-center grid grid-cols-4 top-28">
```

I took if from here-
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/top-right-bottom-left#basic-usage

Comment: I tried it too before, but it didn't work. I use `-top-28` and add `relative` to the class and it works, though!